# Want to check if entered starttime and endtime already exist in starttime and endtime column in oracle database in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, validation, datetime

Want to check if entered starttime and endtime in popup window textbox already exist in starttime & endtime column in table of oracle database in ASP.NET

I am doing daily activity management where user enter every activity done on that particular day.

For eg : If User Enter Startime 16:15 and Endtime 17:30 it should check DB and if same user already entered an activity on that same date and time (Starttime 16:16 and Endtime 17:31)

it should not accept and show error/alert like "Already activity exist on given time"

I want this check to happen on button click of popup window and using same popup window form of click event of every box..plz see below URL

http://postimg.org/image/v6qrhb06h/

Declared starttime and endtime as varchar in oracle

I have tried below query

```
select * from activities 
 where starttime between +TextBox1.Text+ 
       and +TextBox2.Text+ 
 and endtime between +TextBox1.Text+ and +TextBox2.Text+
```

columns and values
**user  Email       activityname  acticvitydescp  starttime endtime  activitydate**
xys  xyz@abc.com    XYZ         done that etc   09:45     11:00   04-MAY-15

it is not satisfying my requirement

Comment: Is there any necessity to keep the date datatype as varchar when oracle supports date datatype?

Comment: @MGPJ i am only getting time [eg: 16:15] input from user and direclty storing that value from textbox to DB

Comment: @MGPJ please see this image url http://postimg.org/image/50wpp1s9v/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 "select * from activities 
 where (to_date(starttime,'HH:MI') between 
 to_date('"+TextBox1.Text+ "','HH:MI') 
 and to_date('"+TextBox2.Text+ "','HH:MI') )
 OR (to_date(endtime,'HH:MI') between 
 to_date('"+TextBox1.Text+ "','HH:MI') 
 and to_date('"+TextBox2.Text+ "','HH:MI'))"
```

Since you are storing date as varchar you need to use to_date() function to convert: use **HH24** if you are saving time in 24 hour format

**Note: Also always go for parameterized queries that will avoid sql injection problems**

```
create table time1
(starttime varchar(20),
 endtime varchar(20)
 );

 insert into time1 values ('16:30','17:45');
 insert into time1 values ('16:32','17:45');
 insert into time1 values ('17:45','18:00');

select * from time1
where to_date(starttime,'hh24:mi') 
between to_date('16:30','hh24:mi') 
and to_date('17:45','hh24:mi') 
and to_date(endtime,'hh24:mi') 
between to_date('16:30','hh24:mi') 
and to_date('17:45','hh24:mi');

STARTTIME   ENDTIME
16:30       17:45
16:32        17:45
```

Comment: @kumartyr see my edited answer..u can use HH24 instead of HH if you are saving hour in 24 hour format

Comment: @kumartyr for teh second activity what is the end time you gave?

Comment: for second activity gave 18:00

Comment: @kumartyr but between will check time between 16:31 and 17:45..si ithinkg issue with time given for endtime

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79315/discussion-between-kumartyr-and-sachu).

Answer (score 0):

I am not an oracle expert, but to use between you should ideally have the fields as datetimes and not VARCHAR.

Then, once you do that you can write a simple query like :

```
"select * from activities 
 where (starttime between '" + TextBox1.Text + "' and '" + TextBox2.Text + "')"
 OR (endtime between '" + TextBox1.Text + "' and '" + TextBox2.Text + "')";
```

I changed added an OR instead of AND as I see you are interested in overlaps.